# "dpkg -L" show wrong install path when i assined custom install path

Tags: linux, dpkg

i'd like to install **[valgrind](http://valgrind.org/)** in custom path. and i use the command

```
dpkg --instdir=/usr/local/valgrind -i valgrind.deb
```

the command executed correctly. and installed in the correct path.

but when i check the `valgrind` installed path by command.

```
dpkg-query -L valgrind
```

it shows the wrong path

- `/usr/lib/...`
- `/usr/etc/...`
- ...

i expecte the result will be show such as

- `/usr/local/valgrind/lib/...`
- `/usr/local/valgrind/etc/...`

i'm not sure whether i use `dkp` command correctly, any one can help me ?

Comment: Is valgrind in your requested path then?

Comment: yes, it is. @StenSoft

Comment: I am experiencing the same problem with a different package. After installing with --instdir, the package.list file in /var/lib/dpkg has default paths. These are the paths rooted in the .deb package, but I would expect them to have a prefix of the instdir argument. This causes the packages to not be removed correctly since dpkg is trying to remove them from the default location.